# How to get an array from a function from another file?

Tags: python, pandas, pyqt

I've got two files, one is a calculation step.py for the other main.py file, it calculates some stuff and assembles an array that array is saved in an Excel file.

The other main.py file should get the array from step.py, I know could just read the information from the Excel file, but I'm sure there is a way to hand over the array (or I really hope so).

step.py:

```
def SimStep(ResultFile,param_list):

    #after some calculation stuff going on...
    Module_P=panda.DataFrame(colums=["some columns",...])*  #here is the array
```

this function is not called in step.py but in main.py:

```
import step as step

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self,..): #there is some PyQt happening
    self.step() #calling the function
    def step(self):
    step.SimStep(self.lineResultsFile.text(),param_list)  #using it for the calculation*
```

Comment: You can just return the array from SimStep function and save it in variable in MainWindow class

Comment: @AnkitArora can you show me how it would look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just return the array from SimStep function

```
def SimStep(ResultFile,param_list):
    # calculation
    Module_P=panda.DataFrame(colums=["some columns",...])*
    return Module_P
```

and store the array in the step function of MainWindow class

```
import step as step

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        self.step()

    def step(self):
        Module_P_array = step.SimStep(self.lineResultsFile.text(),param_list)
        print(Module_P_array)
```